# Is there any mechanism in Windows that would allow for system-wide color-inversion (i.e. night mode)?

Tags: windows, winapi, dwm

One of my favorite Mac OSX apps is Blacktree's Nocturne, which inverts the colors of the whole screen such that you end up with a black-on-white display systemwide that is easy on the eyes in a dark room. [Example.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4GON.png)

I went looking and it seems that there is currently no way of doing this for Windows. The closest you can get are either dark themes, which most apps will ignore (and don't solve the problem anyways - see my comment to Paul's answer below), or apps like F.lux or Friendeye that simply lower the brightness and/or alter color settings, but I found nothing that would actually invert the colors for the whole screen.

So my question is, is it even possible to write an application that would do this in Windows? Do DWM, NVIDIA drivers, or any other part of the graphics subsystem have any API that allow you to manipulate the rendered image at such a basic level? Where would one even being?

Comment: Apps that ignore the system colour scheme, fonts, locale, etc are broken and should be reported to the authors as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question is more than a year old, but a more appropriate answer may be http://arcanesanctum.net/negativescreen/.

Works in windows 8 too, source code is in C#. It may solve straight away your problem, or you may read the source to expand functionality.

Comment: This is absolutely perfect. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2):

One way I can think of:

- inject a DLL that hooks CreateProcess to inject itself into future processes
- hook EndPaint to call GetDIBits, invert everything, and SetDIBits

DLL injection is a pretty common technique. As for hooking, [Microsoft Detours](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/) should work jut fine.

Also, you might upset the antiviruses, so distributing this as a marketed product probably wouldn't be the best of ideas.

Answer (score 2):

This is already a setting in Windows, set the theme to High Contrast:

[image]

Comment: I'd already mentioned themes in my post. These don't achieve the intended effect because even when apps obey them (which is *far* from universal), there are still plenty of places where themes simply don't apply. Take an image that is simply a white rectangle. Nocturne will convert that into to black because it doesn't care what is on the screen, it simply inverts all the colors. Because of things like this, the those themes still leave large chunks of the UI as black on white. Try it out and you'll see, it's actually worse than normal since the white bits are so blinding when they pop up.

Comment: Bummer :-/  As far as I know, there's no feature to do this then - you could look under Ease of Access center though, or perhaps Magnifier does this

Answer (score 1):

You can get something similar with the Magnifier built into Windows7: start it up, click the "-" button so that it's zooming at 100% (therefore no actual magnification!), and then in the Options dialog, check the "Turn on color inversion" checkbox.

Some more details about this at [WikiHow](http://www.wikihow.com/Invert-Colors-on-Windows-7).

Answer (score 0):

Windows has WInAPi C++ lib which names Magnification, so you can apply color tranformations (aka color inversion, grayscale, color blind filters) with it.

NegativeScreen contains wrapper for C#:
http://arcanesanctum.net/negativescreen/

Python wrapper here:
https://pypi.org/project/WinMagnification/